# Show a sequence of images in WPF then close form

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window that shows an open lock.
When the user clicks a button the lock must change to closed, wait a second and then close the windows.

How can I do that using WPF?

Here is my initial xaml:

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Margin="32"
       IsTabStop="False" Click="BtnUnlockClick">
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="/Common.Wpf;component/images/unlocked.png" Visibility="Visible" Name="imgUnlocked"/>
            <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="/Common.Wpf;component/images/locked.png" Visibility="Collapsed" Name="imgLocked"/>
        </Grid>                
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

and C#:

```
private void BtnUnlockClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put only one Image element into the Button's Content.

```
<Button Click="BtnUnlockClick" ...>
    <Image Source="/Common.Wpf;component/images/unlocked.png"/>
</Button>
```

In the Click event handler change its Source, wait a second, then close the Window. The handler method must be declared `async`.

```
private async void BtnUnlockClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var image = (Image)((Button)sender).Content;
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Common.Wpf;component/images/locked.png"));

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    Close();
}
```